# CSS selecting image / vs \

Tags: html, css

I'm using Atom to edit some CSS and for a section class I wanted to put an image there as a background. How come it wouldn't accept the file location using ..\folder\images\image.png but only worked with ../folder/images/image.png?

Is there significance between the forward and backslashes for this? Since in HTML when referencing a different image in the same folder, I'm referencing them through

```
<img src="folder/images/logo.png" alt = "logo" class = "logo">
```

Comment: Backslashes are used for escaping strings, not for paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use of slashes (for HTML only):**
Backslash carries no special significance in HTML while forward slashes serve the purpose of closing tags and specifying URL or file paths regardless of the platform (Windows or Linux).

But file paths for some other languages have incorporated certain platform-dependent code to identify paths in Windows and Linux differently. Backslashes in such languages are used as escape sequence (as mentioned below) and the path for each are given as follows:

Windows - **`C:\\folder\\images\\logo.png`**

Linux/Unix/Mac - **`/folder/images/logo.png`**

**Backslashes in general are used for:**

- File Path in DOS/Windows - e.g. **`C:\foldername\filename.ext`**
- Escape Sequences - In almost all programming languages, escape sequences are used in between strings to carry out special functions.

  e.g. **`"\n"`** refers to a new line, **`"\t"`** refers to a tab, and **`"\\"`** actually equals to a backslash.

**On the other hand, Forward-slashes in general are used for:**

- File Path in Linux/Unix/Mac - e.g. **`/user/foldername/filename.ext`**
- Web Addresses (URLs) - e.g. **`https://www.google.com/`**
- HTML Closing Tags - e.g. **`<HTML>...</HTML>`**
- Divison Operator in all programming languages!

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation! :)

Comment: Welcome buddy! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

> How come it wouldn't accept the file location using
> ..\folder\images\image.png but only worked with
> ../folder/images/image.png?
>
> Is there significance between the forward and backslashes for this?

It sounds like you answered your own question. ;-) Best of luck developing!

Comment: Not really an answer... could go in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## directory separator

To be more specific, file paths includes `\` on Windows, and `/` on Mac/Linux. Use the proper directory separator according to your operating system.

Some languages automatically identify the correct separator and uses constants to allow dynamic deployment across different platforms (e.g: https://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary)

Comment: Hey Narxx! Thanks for the reply. 

So you stated that \ is used on Windows, and / on Mac/Linux..
but this occurred on Windows only, where HTML used a file path with \ while the CSS used /.

Comment: The forward slash is not just Macs and Linux but UNIX and Unix-like systems and the specifications for URIs and URLs. The internet and world wide web, as a whole, was developed on and based on UNIX. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt